# Unable to pass in a argument to a function call within a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `for` loop that calls an outside function using a few parameters. Whenever I add in the iterator to the function definition and where the function is called, I get an error saying `Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch`

Here's the relevant code. I stripped out a few lines, but you get the gist:

```
Function copy_from_datatable(tool_sel As String, _
                             date_total As Integer, _
                             tool_num As Integer _
                             )
    MsgBox "In function, tool_num = " & tool_num


End Function

Sub Program()

    For tool_num = 1 To total_sites

        If tool_sel = "Badging" Then
            MsgBox "vartype " & VarType(tool_num)
            Call copy_from_datatable(tool_sel, _
                                             date_total, _
                                             tool_num _
                                             )
        End If
    Next tool_num 
End Sub
```

Is there anything wrong with how `tool_num` is used in the function call, function definition, or used in the loop? If I remove `tool_num` from everything, this script runs fine

Comment: You need to declare the variables on the `Sub Program()` you need to `Dim tool_sel As String, date_total As Integer, tool_num As Integer`

Comment: You should probably declare all of your variables all of the time. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of each module (better yet, do it once and for all by enabling `Require Variable Declarations` in the VBA editor options). If you haven't done this yet, it might be annoying at first, but it will definitely save you debugging time later on. Finally, with modern VBA there is almost never a good reason to use `Integer`. Use `Long` instead. `Integer` just risks overflow with no benefit in either speed or memory use (since `Integer` will be stored in 32 bits anyway).

Comment: Function `copy_from_datatable` have a Next without For.

Comment: @AhmedAU OP mentioned that they "stripped out a few lines". That is unlikely to be the isse here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare your variables in `Sub Program()` and it will work:

```
Function copy_from_datatable(tool_sel As String, _
                             date_total As Integer, _
                             tool_num As Integer _
                             )
    MsgBox "In function, tool_num = " & tool_num
End Function


Sub Program()
    Dim tool_sel As String
    Dim date_total As Integer
    Dim tool_num As Integer

    For tool_num = 1 To total_sites

        If tool_sel = "Badging" Then
            MsgBox "vartype " & VarType(tool_num)
            Call copy_from_datatable(tool_sel, _
                                             date_total, _
                                             tool_num _
                                             )
        End If
    Next tool_num
End Sub
```

I suggest you to use `Option Explicit` in every `Module`, to avoid this kind of errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm confused where to put the `Option Explicit` statement. If it's at the module level, that means outside of my `Program` definition, right? My editor keeps forcing it into the `copy_from_datatable` definition

Comment: @simplycoding You're welcome. Yes, `Option Explicit` has to be written in the first line of a Module, outside of any `Sub` or `Function`.